# How can I detect encoding of a string which can be japanese, chinese or english and convert to utf8 for display?

Tags: php, html, email, character-encoding

On a php website, I get email from imap and save them in database.

On the other hand, I want to display some of them. That mailbox receive lot of english mails, but also japanese and chinese.

My problem with the following code is that I can't detect all charset. If I arrange the order of the array so chinese chars are ok, that became wrong for other charset.

```
<?php
$subject = "板ｲﾃ淌"; // can be japanese
$subject = "这间面积70平"; // can be chinese
$subject = "This string can have latin1 chars also";

function get_subject($subject);

$encs = array();
$enc[] = "Big5";
$enc[] = "big5";
$enc[] = "euc-kr";
$enc[] = "EU-CN";
$enc[] = "GB2312";
$enc[] = "ISO-8859-1";
$enc[] = "GBK";
$enc[] = "CP936";
$enc[] = "ASCII";
$enc[] = "JIS";
$enc[] = "UTF-8";
$enc[] = "EUC-JP";
$enc[] = "SJIS";
$enc[] = "latin1";
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($this->object_message, $encs);
$subject = mb_convert_encoding($this->object_message, 'UTF-8', $encoding);
$subject = iconv ( 'utf-8', 'ISO-8859-2' , $subject );
return $subject;
?>
```

Comment: Do you need to detect the encoding first?

Comment: Just for the record, the string that you said "Chinese" is in fact Japanese...

Comment: Sorry for that, I just copy/pasted the firsts examples I find. fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't display them, you can't put them into the database correctly either.

You can't detect what encoding bytes are in just by looking at the bytes, except for UTF-8 because
it has unique and restricted patterns. This is what `detect_encoding` does and is therefore useless
for everything but detecting between very small amount of encodings with exclusive properties.

When you receive the email, you should read the encoding header and use that encoding to convert
the data to UTF-8. Do not convert to ISO-8859-2 because it's a tiny charset and you will lose
most characters.

You could use [PHP email parser](https://github.com/plancake/official-library-php-email-parser) which
returns the email contents in UTF-8.

Comment: I need to first construct the "raw content" 'cause I get the mail from an external source with an imap connection. Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293614/how-to-get-raw-email-data-with-the-imap-extension I should adapt for me (I paste that here if anyone has the same problem).

Comment: @Asenar What is the problem? get the raw content -> pass it to the library -> get parsed UTF-8 content.

Comment: how to get the raw content is the problem. That "PHP email parser" works for "simple html or text body", but there is problems when there is attachments

Comment: @Asenar ok so look for a library that does attachment, I am not your personal google slave :)

Comment: Sorry for the notification, I just thought I had to uncheck it because that didn't answered the thing. I think I will contribute to that lib later to fix what's wrong

Comment: @Asenar the exact library in my answer is not the answer but the principle is. The principle is to read encoding from email headers instead of guessing/detection which is **impossible**. Libraries execute this principle. I link to one library as a first result from google, just because it doesn't work for your special needs, doesn't make my answer invalid because my answer's point is not that specific library at all.

Comment: I unchecked it not because of the attachments problems, I fixed that already. That library is just incomplete for handling subjects properly. but I thanks you for your help anyway, and even if that's not answer exactly the question, I re-validated your answer, it was just to be understandable for the next people who will read it.

Comment: @Asenar The only value in my answer is basically that `mb_detect_encoding` is a worthless piece of crap. That is the answer to your question, the library is just a bonus. :P